# An event that fires when number of items in combobox changes

Tags: vb.net, events, combobox, items

VB2010 I have a ComboBox that gets cleared and then populated manually by several processes. I want to update a label with the number of items in the combobox. Am having trouble finding an event that would get fired when the number of items changes or when the contents of the combobox gets changed. Is there an event I can use for this type of thing? I tried TextChanged  but doesn't seem to work for all cases.

Comment: how are the CBOs populated?  are they bound or do you just use `Items.Add`

Comment: I add them manually through Items.Add.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you bind the ComboBox to a BindingList(Of String) and add a handle to the ListChanged event.

```
Private Sub Init()
    Me.list = New BindingList(Of String)
    Me.ComboBox1.DataSource = Me.list
    AddHandler Me.list.ListChanged, New ListChangedEventHandler(AddressOf Me._ListChanged)
End Sub

Private Sub _ListChanged(sender As Object, e As ListChangedEventArgs)
    'Update label
End Sub

Private list As BindingList(Of String)
```

Comment: +1 and it should be mentioned that the BindingList can be created and maintained by some other object: `myCBO.DataSource = otherObj.CBOListOfSomething` which is provided as a RO Prop or function

Comment: ok but now i have to change all my other code to modify the BindingList instead of the ComboBox directly correct?

Comment: ...or you could leave it alone, create a Public method and whenever something else changes a CBO, they just call that method

Comment: Yes. You should update the BindingList and not the ComboBox directly.